# If not GL_QUADS, then how?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm developing a simple 2D game in Java using the LWJGL wrapper for OpenGL.

For the rendering method, I use VBOs. It seems very good and faster the the other rendering methods.
I was reading some articles and was seeking for some questions here on StackOverflow and I discovered that using 2 triangles is better than using one quad, since modern GPUs show only triangles (And it'll be a waste to let the GPU translate that quad into triangles).

The only way I  know is creating 2 buffers for storing the vertex data and the texture coordinates data. and that's for a quad, this is how I do it:

```
int vertexID; //Holding the GL buffer ID for the Vertex
int texCoordsID; //Holding the GL buffer ID for the texture coords

void init(){
    //BufferUtils is a Utility class provided by the SlickUtil library, I use it for creating buffers.
    //Create float buffer for storing vertex data
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4 * 2);
    //Put vertex data inside the buffer
    vertexBuffer.put(new float[]{
        0, 0,
        100, 0,
        100, 100,
        0, 100
    });
    //Rewind the buffer
    vertexBuffer.rewind();

    FloatBuffer texCoordsBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4 * 2);
    texCoordsBuffer.put(new float[]{
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 1
    });
    texCoordsBuffer.rewind();

    vertexID = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    texCoordsID = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordsID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordsBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void render(){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id); //Not so important.

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexID);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordsID);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Now my main question is, how can you split it into 2 triangles instead of 1 quad?
And a side question: does it really matter for a 2D game? does it make a slight change?

Comment: Splitting a quad/rectangle into a triangle is like basic geometry knowledge.

Comment: @Vallentin Does OpenGL offer any function to it or I should just make 4 buffers? 2 for vertex, 2 for texture?

Comment: Why would you want to have 2 vertex buffers? you can simply have a single vertex buffer. You can even have the 2 vertex and 2 texture buffers as a single buffer. It's called [Interleaved Buffers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices).

Comment: Ironically, most implementations decompose quads into triangles anyway. You can see this in action if you try to draw a `GL_QUAD` or `GL_POLYGON` that is not co-planar in some implementations; the first triangle will be rasterized and nothing else will show up. All you have to do is either use indexed triangle lists, strips or duplicate a few vertices. In the indexed triangle list solution, you would actually introduce a new buffer, the index buffer (element array, as GL calls it).

Comment: By the way, do you really need all the low-level functionality in your 2D game? [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) makes many common tasks easier. (for both 2D and 3D game development)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change

```
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

to

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

and add a slightly different **vertex buffer**

```
vertexBuffer.put(new float[]{
     1.0, 1.0
    -1.0, 1.0
     1.0,-1.0
    -1.0,-1.0
});
```

This represents two triangles, two 'points' are the same, so we have only four 'points'.

Just like:

```
x3__x4
| \  |
|  \ | 
x1__x2
```

Comment: When I run my code with those changes nothing seems to appear, I changed the mode in the `glDrawArrays`, and changed the vertexBuffer, what could it be?

Comment: I have no idea how your view is build, but at least, when I look to your buffer above, you just have do change the values, in my example, to something in your range between 0 and 100.

Comment: @OrelBitton: Make sure you are using an identity matrix for projection and modelview if you want that to work. If you do that, the quad will fill your entire screen because you will be drawing in Normalized Device Coordiantes. Otherwise, those points could be literally anywhere after projection.